# How to debug flysystem

Tags: yii2

I install Yii 2 File kit extendsion, and set local file storage success.
Then i config SFTP then run command

```
Yii::$app->fileStorage1->getFilesystem()->createDir('demo')
```

So it not work. and only show result false.
So i don't know what the error.

I try conffig:

```
'fileStorage1' => [
        'class' => '\trntv\filekit\Storage',
        //'baseUrl' => '@storageUrl1',
        //'filesystemComponent' => 'fs'
        'filesystemComponent' => 'sftpFs'
    ],


    'sftpFs' => [
        'class' => 'creocoder\flysystem\SftpFilesystem',
        'host' => 'Myserver',
        'port' => 22,
        'username' => 'u',
        'password' => 'p',
        //'privateKey' => '/path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey',
        // 'timeout' => 60,
         'root' => 'public_html',
        // 'permPrivate' => 0700,
        // 'permPublic' => 0744,
    ],
```

Comment: i set root option so has error Root is invalid or does not exist http://prntscr.com/fg3duj

Comment: I show php infor and has root /home/media/public_html/, then i set root /home/media/public_html/ it's not work, then i change root to /public_html. so it's work